# Are all of the Team Foundation Service features included in Team Foundation Server?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I have all the requirements to install SharePoint 2013, TFS, SQL Server, etc.
I was wondering if all of features included in the Team Foundation Service are available when you install the full version of TFS on site?

This will influence my decision to use either TFSvc or TFS on site.  I would prefer to use the on site option as you cannot backup any of your history, etc. from TFSvc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Team Foundation Service and Team Foundation Server are not continually in sync around which features are in each. Mostly, this is due to the Team Foundation Service being updated every sprint which is roughly every three weeks.  There is a new Release Archive that will let you know about the new features introduced in Team Foundation Service and then when they should appear in Team Foundation Server.

It is available here:  http://tfs.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/release-archive

[image: Release Archive Tracker for Team Foundation Service & Team Foundation Server]

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No.

TFS Service updates every 3 weeks, while TFS "on-premise" is updated every 3 months.  So the on-premise version will always be a little behind the Service (for example TFS on-premise doesn't have Git yet).

However, TFS On-Premise has some things that the Service doesn't:

- You can use TFS Lab
- Customize Process Templates / Work Item Templates